# Functions.php - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I want to change the H1 to H2 in the functions.php from my wordpress site.
I have a child theme. But when I past the code in the functions.php from my child theme I get a fatal error:

`/data/home/secr02/domains/secretsistersblog.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/functions.php:9) in /data/home/secr02/domains/secretsistersblog.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php on line 197"`

I searched on the internet and I think I have to perform a **remove action** first.
But I have little knowledge of php.
Can somebody maybe help me?

This is what is in the original functions.php:

```
function twentyfourteen_widgets_init() {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';
    register_widget( 'Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget' );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => __( 'Main sidebar that appears on the left.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h1>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Content Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
    'description'   => __( 'Additional sidebar that appears on the right.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h1>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h1>',
) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyfourteen_widgets_init' );
```

Thanks.
Johanna

Comment: you missed the error, was it saying duplicate function by any chance?

Comment: Where is your `/inc/widgets.php` file located ??

I mean in `child theme` or `parent theme` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

Add below code in your `child theme's functions.php` file and add/change code in `my_widgets_init` function according your desire.

```
//First Remove Old Action Hook.
remove_action('widgets_init', 'twentyfourteen_widgets_init');

//Register your own hook.
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init');

function my_widgets_init()
{
    /**
     * Add Or Modify Your Code In This Function.
     */

    /***Updated Code***/
    //require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';
    //register_widget( 'Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget' );

    register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Main sidebar that appears on the left.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Content Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
            'description'   => __( 'Additional sidebar that appears on the right.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
            'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay!
The error is gone then and my site is visible.
The only problem is that I can't login to my admin anymore.
I get this error:
'Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget in /data/home/secr02/domains/secretsistersblog.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/inc/widgets.php on line 269'
My inc/widgets.php is in my child theme folder.

Comment: require_once didn't work. What is the class name of the widget class?

Comment: `Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget` in `/inc/widgets.php`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. If I change the class name I get another error. Somehow I have to get rid of that Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget being declared twice, but I have no idea anymore.